# Callback is not a function when remote method recursively calls itself

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

i have the below code when it is called i get an error saying callback in not a function in the last instance of callback. (  callback("UnabletoSetAcessToken") )

```
serviceOffering.ResetToken = function (retried, Data, options, callback) {
    var filterGetSH = 'Set Token';
    retried++;

    if (retried < 4) {
      if (Data.hasOwnProperty('Name')) {
        filterGetSH = { 'where': { 'Name': Data.Name } };
        serviceOffering.setToken(retried, Data, filterGetSH, options, function (error, dataBody) {
          if (error) {
            serviceOffering.ResetToken(retried, Data, filterGetSH, options, callback);
          } else {
            callback(null, dataBody);
          }
        });
      } else if (Data.hasOwnProperty('EntityId')) {
        filterGetSH = { 'where': { 'EntityId': entityData.EntityId } };
        serviceOffering.setToken(retried, Data, filterGetSH, options, function (error, dataBody) {
          if (error) {
            serviceOffering.ResetToken(retried, Data, filterGetSH, options, callback);
          } else {
            callback(null, dataBody);
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
        callback("UnabletoSetAcessToken")
    }
  };
```

i expected the callback to get called if max retry has reached when unsuccessful. I am unable to understand what is wrong here and how to approach this. 
NOTE:- here setToken is a different remote method that when successful with Oauth token or will return error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `setToken` and `ResetToken` does not match when calling.

```
serviceOffering.ResetToken = function (retried, Data, options, callback) {
    var filterGetSH = 'Set Token';
    retried++;

    if (retried < 4) {
      if (Data.hasOwnProperty('Name')) {
        filterGetSH = { 'where': { 'Name': Data.Name } };
        options.filter = filterGetSH;
        serviceOffering.setToken(retried, Data, options, function (error, dataBody) {
          if (error) {
            serviceOffering.ResetToken(retried, Data, options, callback);
          } else {
            callback(null, dataBody);
          }
        });
      } else if (Data.hasOwnProperty('EntityId')) {
        filterGetSH = { 'where': { 'EntityId': Data.EntityId } };
        options.filter = filterGetSH;
        serviceOffering.setToken(retried, Data, options, function (error, dataBody) {
          if (error) {
            serviceOffering.ResetToken(retried, Data, options, callback);
          } else {
            callback(null, dataBody);
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
        callback("UnabletoSetAcessToken")
    }
  };
```